# Retrieving hidden value inside a bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Have been a little stuck with this.

What would the easiest way be for retrieving the value of a hidden type inside the slide of a bootstrap carousel?

in slide number 2 for example I want to retrieve the following instruction

```
 <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
     <div class="topic-content">
         <input type="hidden" id="hdnInstruction" data-instruction = "Click button to proceed to next topic" />
```

using this `var instruction = $("#hdnInstruction").data().instruction;` will retrieve the value as it is found inside the carousel but i want to retrieve the value...only once the user accessed the slide number 2 for example.

Comment: an `active` class is appended to the current active item if I am not wrong. you can use that to wrap a condition around the fetching of `instruction` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the current active state and carousel events.

Like this for example:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {

    $('.showText').text($('#myCarousel .item.active img').data('instruction'));

});
```

Assuming with `value of a hidden type`, you mean the data attribute value like you use it in your example.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/2241/)